# ng-repeat - index of elements in range

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to know index of element in range?

something like:

```
<span ng-repeat="i in ['a', 'b', 2, 333, 4, 5, zzz, 7]"> {{ **index(i)** }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$index` - iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

```
<span ng-repeat="i in ['a', 'b', 2, 333, 4, 5, zzz, 7]"> {{ $index }}</span>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `$index`.

```
<p ng-repeat="value in ['a', 'b', 'c']"> Index= {{ $index }} value= {{ value }} </p>
```

Should output:

```
Index= 0 value= a
Index= 1 value= b
Index= 2 value= c
```